# Optimize MySQL query for Many-To-Many Join on tags

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I need to select all articles that are linked to a particular tag, but I also want all other tags associated with each article. With my limited SQL knowledge, I made the following MySQL query which works, but doesn't seem very efficient.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, c.id AS topic_id, c.name AS topic, GROUP_CONCAT(t.id) AS tag_ids, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) AS tags, a.description
FROM tag t 
LEFT JOIN artifacts_tags j ON t.id = j.tag_id
LEFT JOIN artifact a ON a.id = j.artifact_id
LEFT JOIN topic c ON c.id = a.topic_id

LEFT JOIN artifacts_tags aj ON a.id = aj.artifact_id
LEFT JOIN tag ts ON ts.id = aj.tag_id
WHERE ts.slug = 'summer'
AND a.is_public = 1 
GROUP BY a.id
```

I would appreciate if anyone could suggest a more efficient query.

Actually, I also need similar tags (all tags belonging to the topic that the tag with slug 'summer' belongs to) but I have another query for that. It would be better if I can get similar tags with the same query but I don't know how. The table `tag` has Many-to-One relation with `topic` table.

Comment: How do you measure efficiency? If the query does what you want and dos it in reasonable time and you can easily understand and modify your query, how could it be more efficient? That said, it seems to me that you could replace the LEFT by INNER joins - but that depends on your database content and semantics.

Comment: @AlexMonthy You're right. I should have used INNER joins. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Non-deterministic GROUP BY:**
The SQL retrieves columns that are neither in an aggregate function nor the GROUP BY expression, so these values will be non-deterministic in the result.

**GROUP BY on different tables:**
This will force the use of a temporary table and filesort, which can be a huge performance problem and can consume large amounts of memory and temporary space on disk.

Comment: All columns in the SELECT list are determined bu the `a.id` (primary key of table `article`) in this case so the query retrurns deterministic results.